# MacBook Pro battery drains to empty while sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Pro 13" 2020 model and its battery drains to empty while sleeping. I have tried all the suggestions from the internet and even reset the SMC but the issue still persists. I'm not sure what I can do to fix this issue. I'm attaching the graph of how fast it drains the battery while sleeping.

[image]

Edit:
Here are the logs after running this command `pmset -g log`

https://pastebin.com/PQa1T9TE

Comment: Your machine might not actually be going to or staying asleep. Please amend your question with the portion of the output of the command `pmset -g log` that spans from shortly before you put the laptop to sleep to until shortly after you reboot it from 0% power. I suspect it's waking up constantly when it should be sleeping and I want to see the wake reasons and/or sleep assertions. (You can upload the text to a service like www.PasteBin.com since it will probably be lengthy.)

Comment: I use either `pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "DarkWake" -e "due to"` or `pmset -g log | egrep "\b(Sleep|Wake|DarkWake|Start)\s{2,}"` to select power management items relating to wake and sleep.

Comment: @Gilby That won't necessarily catch everything I'm interested in. It's helpful to see the full context of each sleep cycle.

Comment: Have you read https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334202/macbook-pro-2018-switch-from-sleep-to-darkwake-in-loop-how-to-diagnose/340666#340666 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217433/macbook-pro-continually-wakes-while-in-sleep-mode/379342#379342 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379890/macbook-is-waking-up-from-sleep-while-on-wifi-with-imac/380300#380300 and lots of others.  You need to properly diagnose your problem, but most like culprit is waking for network which can be fixed by setting `tcpkeepalive`.

Comment: @Syed You have only included one hour of logging. You need to capture enough of the log to go from **before you put the machine to sleep** to until **after you reboot the machine after it runs out of power**.